# Netezza not supporting sub query and similar... any workaround?

Tags: sql, subquery, netezza

I'm sure this will be a very simple question for most of you, but it is driving me crazy...
I have a table like this (simplifying):

```
| customer_id | date | purchase amount |
```

I need to extract, for each day, the number of customers that made a purchase that day, and the number of customers that made at least a purchase in the 30 days previous to the current one.

I tried using a subquery like this:

```
select purch_date as date, count (distinct customer_id) as DAU, 
   count(distinct (select customer_id from table where purch_date<= date and purch_date>date-30)) as MAU
from table
group by purch_date
```

Netezza returns an error saying that subqueries are not supported, and that I should think to rewrite the query. But how?!?!?
I tried using `case when` statement, but did not work. In fact, the following:

```
select purch_date as date, count (distinct customer_id) as DAU, 
   count(distinct case when (purch_date<= date and purch_date>date-30) then player_id else null end) as MAU
from table
group by purch_date
```

returned no errors, but the MAU and DAU columns are the same (which is wrong).
Can anybody help me, please? thanks a lot

Comment: Netezza doesn't like subselects in the select line...you are best off writing two queries, one that counts and returns mau, and one that does dau (by date).  turn both those queries into subqueries and join them together on date and select from that.

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to join them based on date, I need the MAU table to be group by date, right? If so, then I have the same problem as before... Would you mind to write the code you are referring to? thanks a lot

Comment: I think the inability to support subqueires in the select line comes from the mystical netezza FPGA logic thats used to distribute the query processor load.  I posted an answer...was guessing a bit.  What you want is two working queries...one to count DAU for a given day, and one to count MAU for the same date.  Group them both by date, call them subqueries in your from clause and join them on date

Answer (score 1):

I don't beleive netezza supports subqueries in the select line...move to the from statement

```
 select pur_date as date, count(distinct customer_id) as DAU
 from table
 group by purch_date

 select pur_date as date, count (distinct customer_ID) as MAU
 from table
 where purch_date<= date and purch_date>date-30
 group by purch_date
```

I hope thats right for MAU and DAU.  join them to get the results combined:

```
 select a.date, a.dau, b.mau
 from
 (select pur_date as date, count(distinct customer_id) as DAU
 from table
 group by purch_date) a

 left join 
 (select pur_date as date, count (distinct customer_ID) as MAU
 from table
 where purch_date<= date and purch_date>date-30
 group by purch_date) b

 on b.date = a.date
```

Comment: But in this case, you will not calculate MAU, as the count(distinct customer_ID) of the second query will still split the count daily, because you are grouping by purch_date. Am I wrong? Thanks for responding

Comment: You are right...we will want this to return the first day in the 30 day time range instead of pur_date.  That'll be a bit of tricksiness...give me a bit

Answer (score 1):

I got it finally :) For all interested, here is the way I solved it:

```
select a.date_dt, max(a.dau), count(distinct b.player_id)
from (select dt.cal_day_dt as date_dt, 
        count(distinct s.player_id) as dau
        FROM IA_PLAYER_SALES_HOURLY s
        join IA_DATES dt on dt.date_key = s.date_key
        group by dt.cal_day_dt
        order by dt.cal_day_dt
) a
join (
        select dt.cal_day_dt as date_dt, 
        s.player_id as player_id
        FROM IA_PLAYER_SALES_HOURLY s
        join IA_DATES dt on dt.date_key = s.date_key
        order by dt.cal_day_dt
) b on b.date_dt <= a.date_dt and b.date_dt > a.date_dt - 30
group by a.date_dt
order by a.date_dt;
```

Hope this is helpful.